# Simplified Knockout nested loops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My project is to create a grid of dates based on my viewModel below. The code works but I’m interested in figuring out if there is an easier way to reach my first inner array “CalendarDateBlocks”.

```
// data = products.productUnits.CalendarDateBlocks
function productViewModel (data) {
    var self = this;
    window.viewModel = self;
    self.productsList  = ko.observable(data);
}
```

Knockout html binding the table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <!-- ko foreach: window.viewModel.productsList-->
           <!-- ko if: ($index()===0)-->
              <!-- ko foreach: ProductUnits -->
                 <!-- ko if: ($index()===0)-->
                    <!-- ko foreach: CalendarDateBlocks -->
                       <th data-bind="text: BlockDate"></th>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                 <!-- /ko -->
              <!-- /ko -->
           <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Json code from server

```
{
   "productsList":[
      {
         "ProductId":1,
         "Title":"Standard",
         "ImageGalleryId":10,
         "ProductUnits":[
            {
               "ProductUnitId":1,
               "ProductId":1,
               "CalendarBlocks":[
                  {
                     "ProductId":1,
                     "ProductUnitId":1,
                     "BlockDate":"09/01/2013"
                  },
                  {
                     "ProductId":1,
                     "ProductUnitId":1,
                     "BlockDate":"09/02/2013"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ProductUnitId":2,
               "ProductId":1,
               "CalendarBlocks":[
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/01/2013"
                  },
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/02/2013"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ProductUnitId":3,
               "ProductId":1,
               "CalendarBlocks":[
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/01/2013"
                  },
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/02/2013"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "ProductUnitId":4,
               "ProductId":1,
               "CalendarBlocks":[
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/01/2013"
                  },
                  {
                     "ProductId":0,
                     "ProductUnitId":0,
                     "BlockDate":"09/02/2013"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

Comment: Why are you using the $index()===0 if statement in there?

Comment: We're creating a calendar grid, the first row <tr> is the head which contains these columns [Product,Unit,Date,Date,Date, etc.] each Product contains multiple ProductUnits and each Unit contains multiple BlockDates. For the header we only need to get the first row of dates. The <!-- ko if: ($index()===0)--> prevents the loop from going through it more than once. Which brings the point and the reason I posted the question, can this simplified?

Comment: If the answer I already posted doesn't do what you are trying to do please create a fiddle so we can understand what you are trying to acheive

Comment: I created a jsfiddle example of my original working code. 

http://jsfiddle.net/X65Dm/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<!-- ko foreach: window.viewModel.products.ProductUnits.CalendarDateBlocks -->
   <th data-bind="text: BlockDate"></th>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I created a modified version with the suggested solution which does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/X65Dm/1/

Comment: This is the message from the browser console.

TypeError: window.viewModel.productsList.ProductUnits is undefined

Comment: Don't use window.viewModel.  Use productsList().ProductUnits or w/e.

Comment: This is still unclear as I could not get it to work. Would it be possible for you to update the fiddle to reflect your comment? thank you.

jsfiddle.net/X65Dm/1